# oracle subquery stored into a variable

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables **table1** and **table2**.

```
create table table1
(
    ID integer,
    reg_number varchar(9),
    primary_number varchar(9),
    act varchar(1)
);
```

```
create table table2
(
    SECONDARY_NUMBER varchar(9),
    table1_id integer
);
```

I need to be able to grab all the rows from table1 that is associated with table2 so after an insert or update on column ***act*** from **table1** to insert those rows into **table3** table.

I have the query but I'm unsure how to store that query into a variable so I can call it into from a trigger.

The query

```
select * from table1 where id in (
with children as (
                                select id pid, primary_number pan from table1
                                where id = 20407              -- current id
                                and primary_number is not null  -- child ids only
                                ),
                                prime as (   
                                select id pid from table1 p
                                inner join children c on c.pan = p.reg_number),
                                sibs as (
                                    select secondary_number sec from table2 c 
                                    inner join prime on prime.pid = c.person_id ),
                                    sibids as (
                                        select id pid from table1 p 
                                        inner join sibs s on s.sec = p.reg_number)
                                        select pid from children
                                        union
                                        select pid from prime
                                        union
                                        select pid from sibids
                                );
```

Thank you

Comment: Please, clarify your question: what should be stored in which table, how it should be calculated. Also describe your requirement in general words, maybe current code can be optimised

Comment: Why do you need to "store the query into a variable" anyway? I'm not sure what that means.